# Google search console: missing "item" field

Tags: wordpress

I get from Google search console this error message: missing "item" field. I don't know how to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Using Google’s [structured data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool), we see that the breadcrumb markup with an error is outside of the Yoast SEO markup. This means that another plugin or theme feature has added breadcrumb markup. Please contact the author or support team for the plugin/theme that adds the breadcrumb markup.

If you are unsure what plugin or theme adds breadcrumb mark, the fastest way to do this is to deactivate all non-Yoast plugins and switch to a standard theme like [Twenty Nineteen](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentynineteen/).

Test this on your development or staging site, if you have one. If not, we recommend using the [Health Check & Troubleshooting](https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/) plugin. This plugin allows you to run a conflict check without affecting normal visitors to your site.

As we can imagine that you’re unfamiliar with checking for conflicts, we’d like to point you to a step-by-step guide that will walk you through the process: [How to check for plugin conflicts](https://kb.yoast.com/kb/how-to-check-for-plugin-conflicts/).

Answer (score 0):

It may Ecommerce website error which is missing the product page "Item" field, when you add on product it may fixing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).